# Spring Data JPA Native Query N + 1 problem

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've run into some code which behaviour is not clear for me.

We have first entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Info")
public class Info {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "data_id")
private Data data;
    
}
```

and second one:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Data")
public class Data {

@Id
private Long dataId
    
}
```

And we have next method for retrieving data:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Info i inner join Data d on d.data_id=i.data_id", 
 nativeQuery = true)
 List<Info> getInfo() {}
```

As nativeQuery = true is present I expect this method make just one SQL select and retrieve me data. But If I take a look at logs actually there are 2 selects:

```
SELECT * FROM Info i inner join Data d on d.data_id=i.data_id;

SELECT * FROM Data d where d.data_id = 123;
```

Why this is happening ? How to fix it to make only one select and retrieve all data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to specify native query fetches without [Hibernate specific APIs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-hibernate-entity-associations-query-many-to-one-join-example). I would suggest you to use a normal JPQL/HQL query:

```
@Query(value = "FROM Info i join fetch i.data")
List<Info> getInfo();
```

This will do the same as your native query but at the same time just run only a single query.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Could you please elaborate ? Which Hibernate specific APIs you mean ? I thought that when you are using native query Hibernate is used only for mapping result set to entity.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a link to the documentation about the API

Comment: I still don't get it - you mean that Spring Data JPA native query are not useful at all ? Why you mentioned Hibernate API ? How its related to Spring Data JPA ?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? It's not possible with plain Spring Data JPA to configure fetches for native queries. If you want that, you need to use Hibernate specific APIs. If you don't want to use Hibernate specific APIs, you have to reformulate your native query as JPQL/HQL query instead, just like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why I should use Hibernate's API for native query if Spring declares that they have that feature by their own. I am not mocking, I really don't understand. I thought in case of using Spring Data JPA  Hibernate is used only like ORM for mapping results from DB to local java classes (entity) and native query is handles by the means of entity manager and it is sent directly to DB. But maybe I am wrong so I am asking :)

Comment: Spring Data JPA is just a "convenience wrapper" around the JPA APIs, but there are cases when you have to write code yourself. Native queries in JPA can at most map to a single entity, but fetches can't be modeled. This is where the Hibernate native API comes to rescue. But like I wrote, just use the JPQL/HQL I wrote in my answer. There is no need to use native queries in your case.